# Need a way to tell Google Earth to exit Street View before loading another KML

Tags: kml

When GE is at street level and I run a different KML file that replaces the existing one GE fails to fly to the new place. If I first exit street level manually and then load the new KML everything works fine.

Is there an option or instruction I can add to the new KML instructing GE to exit street level before it loads the new data?

Answer (score 0):

If the target KML has a LookAt or Camera view with [ViewerOptions](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxvieweroptions) element with streetview disabled then loading that KML will auto-disable street view.

Add this to your KML's LookAt or Camera element.

```
    <gx:ViewerOptions>              
        <gx:option name="streetview" enabled="0"></gx:option>
    </gx:ViewerOptions>
```

Comment: Thank you Jason, but I don't want to disable streetview, just the opposite. Say right now GE is showing a streetview image, and my external application launches a KML with another streetview image, far away... GE fails; it remains "stuck" within the first streetview and fails to fly to the new streetview. It's the streetview to streetview transition that has me stumped.

Comment: Provide some details on how external app is loading the KML. Is external app doing system execute of the Google Earth executable with target KML file or is new KML updated in GE via dynamic NetworkLink??

Comment: Correct, I'm using a simple version of ShellExecute:

Comment: Like this: ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', pchar(<my kml file>), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL), which works fine, as I have been using it for years and years. If GE is closed, or open but not in streetview, it works perfectly. But, if GE is open and already in streetview, then it fails. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Apparently, if GE is in StreetView opening a new KML also in street view will not change to new location unless done so manually.